# Fisher's Exact Test

Tags: r, statistics, contingency

In this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94909/course-of-action-for-2x2-tables-with-0s-in-cell-and-low-cell-counts, OP said that s/he got a p-value  0.5152 while conducted a Fisher's exact test for the following data:

```
    Control Cases
  A   8       0
  B  14       0
```

But I am getting p-value=1 and odds ratio=0 for the data. My R codes are:

```
a <- matrix(c(8,14,0,0),2,2)

(res <- fisher.test(a))
```

Where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test

Haven't used these in a while, but I'm assuming its your column of two 0's:

```
p = choose(14, 14) * choose(8, 8)/ choose(22, 22)
```

which is `1.0`. For odds ratio, read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio

The 0's are either the numerators or the denominators. I think this makes sense, as a column of 0's effectively mean you have a group with no observations in.

Answer (score 0):

You get the strange p-value=1 and OR=0 because one or more of your counts is 0. It should not be computed by the chi-square equation, which through multiplication yields chi-values of 0 for these respective cells:
[Chi square equation, cell-by-cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu7Az.png).

Instead, you should use the **Fisher's exact test** ("fisher.test()") which to some extent can correct for the very low cell counts (normally you should use Fisher's for whenever you have at least 20% of cells with a count of <5). Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23894860 Using the chi-square analysis will require you to correct using the **Yates' correction**, (e.g.: chisq.test(matrix, correct = T)).